# Why do people say that javascript eval() is evil but you get no objections against setTimeout and setInterval etc?

Tags: javascript, eval, settimeout, setinterval

if I am not mistaken eval executes valid code in a given string

```
eval("alert('hey')");
```

and

```
setTimeout("alert('hey')",1000);
```

does just about the same thing, only with a timer. is set timeout just as risky as eval?

Comment: Good question :) And I guess the answer is yes
More here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'd say you hear the same objections. setTimeout (with string and not function parameters) is pretty much the same as eval.

If possible,

```
 setTimeout(function(){ alert ("hey") ; }, 1000);
```

Comment: No reason it shouldn't be possible

Comment: +1 for providing an example of the proper use of `setTimeout`. The ability to pass a string argument has probably done more harm than good to how people use javascript

Comment: +1 Looks like my code needs some security changes ;) thanks, hmm I was not exactly aware that you can use timeouts this way as well hmmm

Answer (score 4):

Because when people say "eval", they mean "eval and any function that is more or less equivalent to eval", but the former is much shorter to say.
So the answer to your question is yes, it is as risky.