# array.push() throws weird error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to push elements into array `X` while iterating through array `Y`. At some point, while pushing a new element into array X, I get an "Unexpected token :" error in the browser console. I am able to push several elements properly before it fails (almost every time around 7th element).

It is recursive function, and maybe that causes an issue... Here is the code:

```
function getPosition(img) {
    var tmpRandPosition = Math.floor(Math.random() * (9));

    if($.inArray(galleryPositions[tmpRandPosition], populatedPositions) != -1) {
        setTimeout("getPosition("+img+")",1);
    } else {
        populatedPositions.push(galleryPositions[tmpRandPosition]);

        return true;
    }
}
```

As you can see from the script, I'm trying to display photos randomly at 8 different positioned elements in HTML.

Comment: I think, its more likely that there is a problem with the filename of that particular image or something like that. Oh, and pass a function instead of a string to that setTimeout.

Comment: The problem was, as @antyrat pointed, in wrong function passing from setTimeout().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems the problem is in the `setTimeout` function. Try to pass the argument to that function using an anonymous function instead of concatenation:

```
setTimeout(function() { getPosition(img) }, 1);
```

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 2):

This will break:

```
setTimeout("getPosition("+img+")",1);
```

as it actually writes:

```
setTimeout("getPosition(img_path.jpg)",1);
```

and tries to evaluate it (using `eval`).

The problem is that JS consider `img_path.jpg` as a variable.

Fix:

```
setTimeout("getPosition('"+img+"')",1);
```

But never do it this way as it's not good or fast to evaluate a string.

Send instead an anonymous function to setTimeout:

**REALFIX:**

```
setTimeout(function() {
    getPosition(img);
}, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Don't call setTimeout with a string argument.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492015/why-do-people-say-that-javascript-eval-is-evil-but-you-get-no-objections-again)  Always use a function.  Using the string in this case subjects this code to injection attacks if the img variable is vulnerable.